# How do I make the image position change in this CSS Sprite when ONLY the link is hovered over?

Tags: css

[My CSS Sprite here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkRcN/7/)

The problem is that the image changes position even when the empty area to the right of links is hovered over with mouse..what I want is the image position to change ONLY when mouse is over those texts ie "Link1", "Link2", etc.

What do I need to change in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [shrinkwrap](http://work.arounds.org/issue/83/shrinkwrapping-elements/) the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/xkRcN/8/

Comment: Which line of code did u change ? I see the same code :/ where do I add this wrap property ? which line? sry but I am new to all this..need help..thnx

Answer (score 1):

Bad HTML! Bad bad HTML! Shrinkwrapping is of course the correct solution, but surely it'll be good to use valid HTML at the same time?

Using the [general sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector), [**this code**](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/DZZwb/) will work *without* causing dozens of validation errors at the same time.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="sprite sp_ID1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="sprite sp_ID2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="sprite sp_ID3">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="sprite sp_ID4">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="sprite sp_ID5">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#" class="sprite sp_ID6">Link 6</a>

    <div class="sp_ID0"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sprite {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;  /* These two lines are where the shrinkwrapping occurs */
    clear: both;
    color: white;
}

.container, .sp_ID0 {
    width: 600px;
    height: 203px;
}
.sp_ID0 {
    background-image: url(http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4106/5064283850_fc6b5fac15_b.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.container  {
    position:relative;
}

.sp_ID0 {
    z-index: -2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
}

.sp_ID1:hover ~ .sp_ID0 { background-position: 0px -203px; }
.sp_ID2:hover ~ .sp_ID0 { background-position: 0px -406px; }
.sp_ID3:hover ~ .sp_ID0 { background-position: 0px -609px; }
.sp_ID4:hover ~ .sp_ID0 { background-position: 0px -812px; }
.sp_ID5:hover ~ .sp_ID0 { background-position: 0px -203px; }
.sp_ID6:hover ~ .sp_ID0 { background-position: 0px -406px; }
```

Comment: thnx for the help but this is not working fine in my browser..it won't change images on hover